# How to stack information from different variables?

Tags: variables, stack, append, sas

Help!

I have 2 variables from different datasets. Each variable has a different name in each dataset.  However, the variables are delivering the same type of information for a single resspondent.

Ex.

Variables 1 & 2 for respondent #1

**DR1IFDCD**
11111000
32104950
51101010
81103080
11111000

**DR1IFDCD**
92410310
92101000
12210250
31105000
22300140

Any Guidance will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to *merge*, not stack.  In that case, sort your datasets, then merge them...

```
proc sort data=data1;
    by respondentid;
run;
proc sort data=data2;
    by respondentid;
run;

data newdata;
    merge data1 data2;
    by respondentid;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to stack (append), there are 2 ways...

```
data newdata;
    set data1 data2;
run;
```

or...

```
proc append base=data1 data=data2;
run;
```

The latter approach appends one onto the other instead of creating a new dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables have different names (name01 for data set data1, name02 for data set data2), you could join the two data sets like this

```
data newdata;
   set data1(rename=(name01=finalname)) data2(rename=(name02=finalname));
run;
```

assuming that the data type and length are the same.